# combobox saves ID instead of item name

Tags: ms-access

I have a Printer Inventory system. I have Make, Model, Inventory tables and set relations between them.
Make holds Printer's Manufacture name such as HP, Dell, etc.. it has ID field as primary key autonumbering and Model has ID, Model, MakeID fields which MakeID is the ID from Make table.

In one form I have two Combo Box cbMake and cbModel I was able to set so when I choose Dell on cbMake the cbModel data is the Dell printer's model and if I change the cbMake to HP the cbModel is HP.

Problem that I have is when I save the data on my Inventory Table instead of saving Printer Make and Model it saves the ID number of the Printer Make and Model like I choose Dell which ID is one then Model XYZ which ID is 22 then 1 and 22 is being saved in my Inventory table.

How can I change this to save Dell and XYZ instead of the numbers?

Comment: Why would you NOT want to save ID's since those have been designated primary key? That's what they're for - so descriptive data is not replicated across tables. If you want to save descriptive text then set it as PK and don't use autonumber keys.

Comment: Thanks for info I change the primary key and it works. I guess I did not needed the key (ID) from the beginning

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because issue was db design, not  programming.